# Iptables source mac match not always matching?

Tags: linux, iptables, openwrt

I have added some rules to my PREROUTING chain in NAT.
Usually at the beginning of a new machine joining the network, these matches don't always match correctly?

Im using iptables v1.4.21 on OpenWRT Barrier Breaker
This is on a linux bridge where ebtables is sending packets through iptables

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
```

In it's simplest form

```
    -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source <my mac> -j ACCEPT
    -A PREROUTING -m limit --limit 1/min -j LOG --log-prefix "id=Unknown-Device " --log-level 5
```

But I get log messages showing that it didn't match. The mac addresses are definitely correct

```
id=Unknown-Device IN=br-lan OUT= PHYSIN=wlan0 MAC=<dst>:<src>:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.105 DST=15.72.255.5 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=23058 DPT=80 WINDOW=8688 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: Is the client with <my-mac> connected via Ethernet or WIFI ?

Comment: It can occur on both. WAN is bridged with WLAN0 and LAN

Comment: Have you checked the case of the MAC address? Simple but might help!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, your setup is working, and sometimes, when a new machine is connecting, some logs shows up. You are tring to understand why. Is that true?

I have several ideas about your issues, although I can't provide an answer yet.

First, I want to be sure there are some "good" connections. To confirm this, you could disable the 1 packet per minute limitation in the log rule, and add another log rule before the accept one :

```
-A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source <my mac> -j LOG --log-prefix "id=Well-known-Device " --log-level 5
-A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source <my mac> -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "id=Unknown-Device " --log-level 5
```

In order to dismiss some hypothesis, can you confirm that:

1. you are not using DNAT in the nat table (it looks like you aren't)
2. packets are going through FORWARD chain (it looks like they are)
3. it occurs over ethernet (it looks like it does)

Comment: 1. In the real rules I am using DNAT, instead of jumping to accept I jump to a chain that may DNAT certain requests to the bridges IP. But this is only if the MAC matches.

Comment: 2. Correct. Almost all packets correctly match the MAC filters and proceed as expected.

Comment: 3. Yes, it occurs over wireless and ethernet interfaces

Comment: Damn, I'm not sure I still can help then. In your custom chain (the one into you jump from prerouting), have you some `-j RETURN`? Do you end the chain with a global `-j ACCEPT`?

Comment: The custom chain either ends on a -J ACCEPT or a DNAT (i dont need a return for either I didn't think)

Comment: I agree. Wanted to be sure you had no return. Sorry I can't help finally. Good luck anyway.

Comment: What would a RETURN have meant?

Comment: You would have returned in prerouting, just after the rule where you jumped in your custom chain.